# Compare value to array of strings using StartsWith

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, comparison

I have an array:

```
string[] exceptions = new string[] { "one", two", "one_1", "three" };
```

.. I want to be able to say:

```
var result = from c in myCollection
             where not c.Property[3].Value.StartWith(exceptions)
             select c;
```

So I want `myCollection` to be filtered to only show those records whose `Property[3].Value` does **not** `StartWith` a value in the exceptions array. I know StartsWith doesn't take a collection so I'm unsure if this is possible via LINQ or not.

Is this possible in LINQ?! Or am I trying to shoehorn my problem into a LINQ solution?

**EDIT:** I should say, Contains is not an option since I only want to exclude elements whose property startswith the exception string.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var result =  myCollection.Where(c =>  
                           exceptions.All(e => 
                                       !c.Property[3].Value.StartsWith(e));
```

Comment: This one worked for me first time and was a one-liner. Thank you.

Comment: The query returns collections with property does not start with ANY exception string, `!Any()` return true even a property does not start single exception but we need to ensure this for all exceptions, I believe there is some confusion with word `ANY`

Comment: @pierre : nice to hear, I would suggest covering such logic by unit tests looking forward

Comment: With `All` it won't ever return any results. It should be `Any`.

Comment: looks like there is some confusion, we have to ask OP what is work for him

Comment: From my point of view you guys right so it should be `Any()`, I will update my answer when @pierre confirm this since answer already acepted

Comment: @pierre: can you confirm that `All()` won't work and `Any()` gives you right results so I will update my answer

Comment: I've found what I've missed, NOT should be before `StartsWith()` not before the `(All)`,

Comment: The logic of "All Not Starts With" is the same as "Not Any Starts With". Quite different from "Not All Starts With". Well done on fixing the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
string[] exceptions = new string[] { "one", "two", "one_1", "three" };

var result = from c in myCollection
            where !exceptions.Any(exception =>
                c.Property[3].Value.StartsWith(exception))
            select c;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use IndexOfAny (and check result is index position zero) as that takes a collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the collection of item you don't want then do a IEnumerable.Except().

I should look like this :

```
var result = from c in myCollection               
             where not c.Property[3].Value.StartWith(exceptions)               
             select c;  

var finalResult = myCollection.Except(myCollection.Select(i => i.StartWith(exception)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = myCollection
              .where(
                 rs=>exceptions
                 .where(
                     rs1=>!rs.property[3].value.startsWith(rs1)
                  )
              )
```