# C# Searching for files and folders except in certain folders

Tags: c#, .net, linq, file, directory

Is there any way to exclude certain directories from SearchOption using LINQ command [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172075/get-all-files-except-zip)

```
string path = "C:\SomeFolder";

var s1 = Directory.GetFiles(path , "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

var s2 = Directory.GetDirectories(path , "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

The path consists of Sub1 and Sub2 Folders with certain files in it. I need to exclude them from directory search.

Thanks

This Worked:

```
string[] exceptions = new string[] { "c:\\SomeFolder\\sub1",
"c:\\SomeFolder\\sub2" };

var s1 = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\x86", "*.*",
SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(d => exceptions.All(e =>
!d.StartsWith(e)));
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240861/compare-value-to-array-of-strings-using-startswith) helped with Exceptions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No there isn't as far as I know. But you could use very simple LINQ to do that in a single line.

```
var s1 = Directory.GetFiles(path , "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(d => !d.StartsWith("<EXCLUDE_DIR_PATH>")).ToArray();
```

You can easily combine multiple exclude DIRs too.

Comment: Here you're actually filtering the returned files, not the directories.

Comment: @Olly: `GetFiles()` returns fully qualified paths of all files, so doing a `Where` with `StartsWith()` will essentially return what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Ah, yes. Nice and simple!

Answer (score 6):

You can't do exactly what you want with simple LINQ methods.  You will need to write a recursive routine instead of using `SearchOption.AllDirectories`.  The reason is that you want to filter *directories* not *files*.

You could use the following static method to achieve what you want:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(
    string rootDirectory,
    Func<string, bool> directoryFilter,
    string filePattern)
{
    foreach (string matchedFile in Directory.GetFiles(rootDirectory, filePattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
    {
        yield return matchedFile;
    }

    var matchedDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectory, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        .Where(directoryFilter);

    foreach (var dir in matchedDirectories)
    {
        foreach (var file in GetFiles(dir, directoryFilter, filePattern))
        {
            yield return file;
        }
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
var files = GetFiles("C:\\SearchDirectory", d => !d.Contains("AvoidMe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase), "*.*");
```

**Why the added complexity?**  This method completely avoids looking inside directories you're not interested in.  The `SearchOption.AllDirectories` will, as the name suggests, search within *all* directories.

If you're not familiar with iterator methods (the `yield return` syntax), this can be written differently: just ask!

## Alternative

This has *almost* the same effect.  However, it still finds files within subdirectories of the directories you want to ignore.  Maybe that's OK for you; the code is easier to follow.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFilesLinq(
    string root,
    Func<string, bool> directoryFilter,
    string filePattern)
{
    var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(root, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(directoryFilter);

    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    foreach (var d in directories)
    {
        results.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(d, filePattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Like your nice xample most of all

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var s2 =  Directory.GetDirectories(dirPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
         .Where(directory => !directory.Contains("DirectoryName"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
///used To Load Files And Folder information Present In Dir In dir
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo[] fileInfoArr;
        StringBuilder sbr=new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbrfname = new StringBuilder();
        string strpathName = @"C:\Users\prasad\Desktop\Dll";
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(strpathName);
        fileInfoArr = dir.GetFiles("*.dll");

        //Load Files From RootFolder
        foreach (FileInfo f in fileInfoArr)
        {
            sbrfname.AppendLine(f.FullName);
        }
        DirectoryInfo[] dirInfos = dir.GetDirectories("*.*");
       //Load Files from folder folder 
        foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dirInfos)
        {
           fileInfoArr = d.GetFiles("*.dll");
           foreach (FileInfo f in fileInfoArr)
           {
               sbrfname.AppendLine(f.FullName);
           }
            sbr.AppendLine(d.ToString());

        }
        richTextBox1.Text = sbr.ToString();
        richTextBox2.Text = sbrfname.ToString();
    }
```