# How to check for a specific file and delete it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

i am using a C# winform in which i wanted to search for a particular file in a folder and i want to delete it.
How can i do this. i am trying with the below codes.

```
  private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string Filename = img_path.Text; // here i have the filename "sample.grf"
         if (Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\Debug").Where(x => x.Name == Filename).Any()) // getting error here
        {
           // i want to search here in above folder and delete the file.. how to do this
                System.IO.File.Delete(/dont know how to delte the particular file);

        }
       }
```

please help out

Comment: Why not simply use `File.Exists` ? Also what is the error you are getting

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles` will not return a `FileInfo[]` as you assumed, use `if (new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\Debug").GetFiles().Where(x => x.Name == Filename).Any())` but simply you can do `if(File.Exists(Path.Combine(@"E:\Debug", Filename)))`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403463/c-sharp-searching-for-files-and-folders-except-in-certain-folders

Comment: x is a string so maybe x == Filename, and I think everybody is missin gthe point with the fact that he may not know the entire path . just the filename.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply done this way:

```
File.Delete(Path.Combine(@"E:\Debug", Filename));
```

No need to check if the file exists first. If it doesn't, `File.Delete` will simply do nothing.

If you may have any security concern (like a user entering `..\SomethingElse\Important.doc` for instance), you need to ensure the field only contains a file name. One way would be:

```
if (Filename.ToCharArray().Intersect(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()).Any())
    return;
```

So your whole function may look lie this:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Filename = img_path.Text;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Filename))
        return;

    if (Filename.ToCharArray().Intersect(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()).Any())
        return;

    File.Delete(Path.Combine(@"E:\Debug", Filename));
}
```

Also, `button4_Click` is not a very friendly name to maintain. You may want to consider renaming the button and that function to something meaningful.

Comment: Remove all of your code inside `button4_Click`, and just add that one line: `File.Delete(Path.Combine(@"E:\Debug", img_path.Text));`

Comment: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @RadioSpace yes I noticed that and edited my comment right after I posted it (refresh the page)

Comment: Error :- `The process cannot access the file '\\bin\Debug\sample.grf' because it is being used by another process.`
using the abve file to send to a printer. After that i need to delete. Is there any way i can wait untill the process is finished and then delte the file

Comment: @StacyKebler you have to close all file handles on the file before attempting to delete it. As I don't know what you're doing with the file elsewhere in your code I can't help much more here. This is a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the file, just `Delete()` it:

```
File.Delete("C:\\mypath\\myfile.txt");
```

There is no exception thrown for a file that already does not exist, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.90).aspx).