# How to search Top Level Directory and Only One Child Directory

Tags: c#

I have a directory structure something this:

```
parent
    file1
    file2
    childFolder1
    childFolder2
    .
    .
    .
    specialChildFolder
         file3
         file4
```

Basically I want to get a list of all the files in the `parent` and `specialChildFolder`.  I did find this question [C# Searching for files and folders except in certain folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403463/c-sharp-searching-for-files-and-folders-except-in-certain-folders) which excludes particular child folders.  There is only one child folder in my case that needs to be searched for files, so creating a long list of folders to be excluded seems backwards to me.  It seems to me there should be a way to use a combination of `Directory.GetFiles` and `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to match the specific child directory, but I haven't been able to figure out the correct way to do that yet.

EDIT:
The current code is:

```
string someFileLoc = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string fileLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(someFileLoc);
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fileLocation);
```

This currently gets the files from the parent folder (which is really bin), but not the child folder.

DISCLAIMER:  I only have roughly a month of C# experience so this might be a painfully easy problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use recursion to test do perform a directory of the CURRENT folder and pass in a "level" parameter (int) which you reduce every time you call against a SUB folder.  Only recurse further if the level is > 0.  That way you can run it against any arbitary number of sub folders.

Can you provide the code you have so far and we can show you how to do this.