# How to delete (or exclude) something in a string[]

Tags: c#

I want to exclude or delete something in a string[]. The code is:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\TEST\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

For example, I want to exclude the folder 3 from the "TEST" folder (see screenshot below).

How can I do this?

Edit: Note that the folder is not included in the string[] so I can't delete it from here. Folder "3" need to be excluded from "SearchOption.AllDirectories" so the files in it are not taken.

[image]

Comment: I think you can use `List<string>` instead of string array: `var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\TEST\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList()` and `list.Remove("3")` to remove "3" folder from list.

Comment: Edited post to explain more on my problem

Comment: I think you have a solution there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403463/c-sharp-searching-for-files-and-folders-except-in-certain-folders.

Comment: With this you can exclude the Directory that you want
`string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\TEST\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(p => string.Compare(Path.GetDirectoryName(p), "D:\\TEST\\3", false) != 0).ToArray();`