# Copy all folder EXCEPT certain folder and file in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to copy all the folder and file from "source" to "target" EXCEPT some directory(systemdir).

This method I reference to:
[C# Searching for files and folders except in certain folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19403463/12426763)

but I found out my result I have some problem:

In the source directory if there are "Intel" or any folder start with "Intel" such as "Intel123", it will exclude it together. So I wish to copy the folder exactly the folder I mention and not all included the directory name.

Feel free to share if there are any other method.

Following is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string serialNum = "MS001";
            string userName = Environment.UserName;
            string sourcecpath = "C:\\Users\\" + userName + "\\Desktop\\Dummy\\Local C";
            string targetcpath = "C:\\Users\\" + userName + "\\Desktop\\Dummy\\Desktop\\" + serialNum + "\\Local C";
            copy(sourcecpath, targetcpath);
        }

    public static void copy(string source, string target)
    {

        string[] systemdir = new string[] {  "Error", "Intel", "PerfLogs", "Program Files", "Users", "Windows" };

        for (var i = 0; i < systemdir.Length; i++)
        {
            systemdir[i] = source + "\\" + systemdir[i];
        }

        //Now Create all of the directories
        foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(source, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(d => systemdir.All(e => !d.StartsWith(e))))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dirPath);
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(dirPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(source, target));
            }

        }

        //Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
        foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(source, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(newPath.Replace(source, target))))
            {

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(newPath))
                {
                    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(source, target), true);
                    // Use a try block to catch IOExceptions, to
                    // handle the case of the file already being
                    // opened by another process.
                    try
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(newPath);
                    }
                    catch (System.IO.IOException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

EDIT suggested by(Simply Ged):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string serialNum = "MS001";
            string userName = Environment.UserName;
            string sourcecpath = "C:\\Users\\" + userName + "\\Desktop\\Dummy\\Local C";
            string targetcpath = "C:\\Users\\" + userName + "\\Desktop\\Dummy\\Desktop\\" + serialNum + "\\Local C";
            copy(sourcecpath, targetcpath);
        }

    public static void copy(string source, string target)
    {

        string[] systemdir = new string[] {  "Error", "Intel", "PerfLogs", "Program Files", "Users", "Windows" };

        for (var i = 0; i < systemdir.Length; i++)
        {
            systemdir[i] = source + "\\" + systemdir[i] + "\\";
        }

        //Now Create all of the directories
        var directoryList = Directory.GetDirectories(source, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(d => !systemdir.Any(e => d.StartsWith(e)));

        foreach (string dirPath in directoryList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dirPath);
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(dirPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(source, target));
            }

        }

        //Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
        foreach (var directory in directoryList)
        {
            foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(source, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(newPath.Replace(source, target))))
                {

                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(newPath))
                    {
                        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(source, target), true);
                        // Use a try block to catch IOExceptions, to
                        // handle the case of the file already being
                        // opened by another process.
                        try
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(newPath);
                        }
                        catch (System.IO.IOException e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the dirPath needed to add "\\" so it able to compare with the systemdir array:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string serialNum = "MS001";
            string userName = Environment.UserName;
            string sourcecpath = "C:\\Users\\" + userName + "\\Desktop\\Dummy\\Local C";
            string targetcpath = "C:\\Users\\" + userName + "\\Desktop\\Dummy\\Desktop\\" + serialNum + "\\Local C";
            copy(sourcecpath, targetcpath);
        }

    public static void copy(string source, string target)
    {

        string[] systemdir = new string[] { "Error", "Intel", "PerfLogs", "Program Files", "Users", "Windows" };

        for (var i = 0; i < systemdir.Length; i++)
        {
            systemdir[i] = source + "\\" + systemdir[i] + "\\";
            Console.WriteLine(systemdir[i]);
        }

        //Now Create all of the directories
        foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(source, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            string dirPath2 = dirPath + "\\";
            if (!systemdir.Any(dirPath2.Contains))
            {
                if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(dirPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(source, target));
                }
            }

        }

        //Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name

        foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(source, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(newPath.Replace(source, target))))
            {

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(newPath))
                {
                    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(source, target), true);
                    // Use a try block to catch IOExceptions, to
                    // handle the case of the file already being
                    // opened by another process.
                    try
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(newPath);
                    }
                    catch (System.IO.IOException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you Simply Ged for your assist.

Answer (score 0):

You can append a `\\` to the end of the `systemdir` variables:

```
systemdir[i] = source + "\\" + systemdir[i] + "\\";
```

This would only match folders that are the exact name

e.g. `C:\Windows\Intel\`

In addition to this you can improve you loop and only loop over the items in the `systemdir` array

```
for (var i = 0; i < systemdir.Length; i++)
{
    systemdir[i] = source + "\\" + systemdir[i];
}
```

If you add or remove items from this array then the loop will automatically handle it

**EDIT**

You `Where` clause isn't excluding the items. You need to change it to:

```
.Where(d => !systemdir.Any(e => d.StartsWith(e)))
```

Translated as:

where `systemdir` does not have any that match the start of `d`

**EDIT**

As mentioned in your second comment, your second `foreach` is using the `source` folder to find out what files and directories to copy, which isn't excluding the `systemdir` folders. You need to store a list of the directories you want to process in a variable:

```
var directoryList = Directory.GetDirectories(source, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(d => !systemdir.Any(e => d.StartsWith(e)));
```

This list now contains only the directories you want to copy i.e. it has excluded the ones from you `systemdir` array.

You can now change your first `foreach` to use that variable:

```
foreach (string dirPath in directoryList)
{
    ...
}
```

Now we loop through the same list process the directories you need to copy:

```
foreach (var directory in directoryList)
{
    //Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
    foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I used the solution you are given, it show that all the folder is copied including the one I would like to excluded.

Comment: Sorry, I still get the same result as previous(it show that all the folder is copied including the one I would like to excluded.).

The code I post should it will exclude folder but the folder with same start also being excluded.

If my code is not clear enough feel free to ask for justification. Thank.

Comment: I has added the full code of my program.

create a folder at Desktop called Dummy;

Inside Dummy create 2 folder "Local C" , "Desktop";

Inside C create 3 folder "Intel", "Intel1", "Intel 2";

see the "intel1" and "Intel 2" success copy to the destination or not.